# Which potatoes are best for twice baked potatoes

Tags: potatoes

Which potatoes in the US are best for twice baked potatoes? 
My twice baked potatoes didn't turn out right. The skins broke, and punctured to easily. I was using Yukon golds of medium size lightly washed, and punctured with a fork.

Comment: This needs a country or region tag. Availability of potato races differs widely across the world.

Comment: How were you scooping out the insides?  I use Yukon Gold, but split them open to let them cool for a minute or so, then use a spoon (with not to blunt of an edge), to gently scrape them out, while holding the potato half in my hand.  If it feels like it's starting to break, I flip it over and work from the other side ... and I don't try to make them *too* thin ... maybe half an inch or so (~1.25 cm)

Comment: @JanDoggen That's not how we use tags here, really... I know that some sites do but we tend to reserve the "country-cuisine" tags for questions about that cuisine, not to indicate where the OP is. Please note the Tag Wiki Excerpt for American Cuisine specifically says not to use the tag for ingredient differentiation: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-cuisine

Comment: @Catija Ah, good. Not a tag then - in the question is fine as well.

Comment: I split them, and let cool. Then used a spoon. I am sorry for not using the tags right. I appreciate you letting me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main types of potatoes: starchy and waxy (although some are considered in-between). The difference, as you might imagine, has to do with the starch content of the potatoes.

When cooked, starchy potatoes (like Russet potatoes) tend to break apart. They are often used in baking and frying. They also are more absorbent of liquids and fats.

Waxy potatoes (like red potatoes) hold together more when they are cooked. They are more likely to be used in soups and stews. They also tend to have thinner skins than starchy potatoes.

Yukon gold potatoes are considered in-between starchy and waxy. Their medium levels of starch make them a good all-around potato.

But if the Yukon gold potatoes aren't working, I'd suggest using a starchier potato. One of the things that makes twice-baked potatoes so good is that the inside is mixed with other ingredients and then reheated. Starchy potatoes are more likely to absorb the butter/cheese/other ingredients.

Comment: Twice baked potatoes also benefit from a thicker skin, to hold things together. Something like a red potato doesn't have that because, as you noted, the skin is incredibly thin.

Answer (score 1):

I have made twice baked potatoes many times. I have found Russet potatoes hold up the best. I bake them in the oven till they are slightly under done. 350F for about 50 minutes with out poking the skin. I know they can possibly explode but, I've only happen to me once and that was microwaving so I think you should be safe with oven cooking. Remove the potatoes form the oven and let cool. Cut in half and remove most of the flesh of the potato, leaving about 1/8' to 1/4' of flesh on the inside of the skin. Mix the potato flesh with what ever you want to add to it. I'm a big fan of blue cheese caramelized onions and sauteed mushrooms, or broccoli and cheddar. For a crispier skin place the unfilled skins on a baking sheet and bake for another 15 minutes at 350F, allow to cool and then stuff. Stuffed potatoes back in the oven at 350F for 30-40 minutes.